# Which type of USB socket is this?

Tags: usb

I am looking to replace this USB port on a new laptop which snapped inside the connector.

I know it is a USB 3.0 socket, but not sure on the exact part number or type of socket.

I found this online: http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/maplin-usb-30-socket-a-pcb-n08jt which looks very similar, but the one I need seems to mount in the middle of the PCB, rather on the top

Any help would be great.

[image: Usb socket of unknown type]

Comment: You're looking for a board cutout through hole usb A (right angle obv). It would be helpful if it had something useful printed on it, like Molex tends to print their name on their usb connectors.

Comment: This is the closest fit I found on Mouser: http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Molex/48395-0003/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMulM8LPOQ%252bykwA5NqHGuO67U2SDR9cuvQBRG074DIXNEQ%3d%3d You'll want to get measurements on the pads and check them against any potential connectors you find. Actually this one looks closer: http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Wurth-Electronics/692121330100/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMulM8LPOQ%252byk1QA3g9HKJE0ZRnrV4mqiYo%3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sort of connector would usually be referred to as a 'board-cutout' or 'mid-mount'.
Molex has a few options in their 4839x series which you could source from RS (for instance http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/type-a-usb-connectors/8129632/), but you'll have to show some more detail for your connector, like a view from the back showing its connections to the PCB, to be more certain.

Comment: Marked as the answer for the source mainly, as this seems to be what I need. Although I wish I could mark all the answers as correct.

Answer (score 4):

It is called a "Mid Mount" or "Board Cut Out" type USB connector.  You also need to determine the exact format, eg. pin 1 being on the left or right - as viewed from top, 4 or 5 total pin format, then compare that to the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be difficult but it's possible.

To start, you should unsolder the usb connector. You might find some clues on the bottom but it's unlikely.

More importantly, you'll want a good drawing of the footprint that includes dimensions of the solder pads, distances of throughholes and any other mounting features. Next you'll need to compare datasheets for something that will match. I would recommend going to [digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv392=1677&pv392=4024&FV=fff40016%2Cfff802e4&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=250) or mouser and doing a search there. Take careful note of the 3d dimensions too so that it'll fit your laptop's enclosure. Many of them are going to look the same across different vendors since these things are very standard. However, it only takes one pad of a different size to ruin the fit. Good luck!

Comment: Ah I see... I planned to solder this myself, but there are 9 pins to solder, 5 of them hidden. Looks like I might not be able to replace this. Thanks

Comment: 5 pins are hidden from the bottom as well? Is there some kind of shroud covering the pins on the bottom? Usually the bottom of the board will have the pins in the open

Comment: I'm guessing OP has difficulty removing the PCB from its mounts precluding them from reaching the bottom. If this is the case, I would not advice further work unless you are willing to risk damaging the entire laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Looks similar to [this](http://katalog.we-online.de/em/datasheet/692121330100.pdf) one (photo credit to [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/692121330100/732-3149-1-ND/2627302)):

[image]

Comment: Looks like thew one! Just to find a seller! Thanks!

Comment: Get someone with a good desoldering tool to remove the pins- the mombo will be multilayer and will suck heat away like crazy. Personally, I prefer to cut the connector apart and remove the pins individually to minimize the chances of damaging the board.

Comment: ^I second that. Since there's no need to save the broken connector, cut most of it off then desolder whats left of the pins. Will do less damage to the board that way.